# DTDeviceKit: deviceType Null

Tags: ios, visual-studio, flutter, flutter-test

initiated 'flutter run' in VS code and getting the following error:

2020-05-02 16:23:57.827 xcodebuild[97219:3069326]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from
    00008030-000D35311160802E was NULL

Any suggestions on what this means?

Comment: have you find out the solution of this problem?

Comment: Do you have any updates on this? I have the same problem on the current stable Flutter release. Thx a lot!

Comment: facing the same problem for the watch device

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
pod deintegrate
pod update
flutter clean
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and what resolved it for me, was the following:

- Open YourProjectFolder/ios/Runner.xcworkspace
- Build the Runner project
- Go back to your flutter project and try to run it again

The first build output on the console said

> Xcode build failed due to concurrent builds, will retry in 2 seconds

Don't do anything, just wait another minute or two and then it works (for me, at least).